# How to read SiteMinder header in Angular 4

Tags: angular, authentication, single-sign-on, siteminder

I am using SiteMinder for SingleSignOn (SSO) authentication. On Successful authentication how do I read SM_USER header from SiteMinder in my Angular 4 code.

Can someone please help in reading this header value?

Answer (score 1):

The SiteMinder headers are *request* headers. They are injected into the request on the server side. Javascript or HttpClient will not be able to see these headers as they are not transmitted to the client.

If you need to determine the username on the client side then you will have to create a server-side web service that can echo out the header

Answer (score 0):

You can read a header from a http response as this :

assuming `http` is an instance of `HttpClient` :

```
http.get(authenticationUrl).subscribe(
    (response: Response) => { console.log(response.headers); }
)
```

you can instead get the header you want, like with `response.headers['SM_USER']` if this is the exact name of the header.

If for some reasons you don't see the header you seek, you can `http.get(url, {observe: 'response'})` instead of the one-parameter get method.

You can have a look [at the documentation here](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

Comment: Hi @Pac0, Thanks for your reply, but I can't do it like this as I don't have the authenticationUrl. It's authenticated by SiteMinder. After successful authentication it will send the SM_USER header.

Comment: @Sriks, I see, I am sorry I have misunderstood your question, because it stated "On successful authentication", I was assuming you already did the authentication part.